# Configure hadoop to tolerate server failures

Tags: hadoop2, fault-tolerance

I am trying to configure a 50-node Hadoop 2.6.0 cluster for failure tolerance. Specifically, I'd like to be able to suddenly stop 5 servers and still have my job complete. So far, stopping even 1 server causes my job to fail with too many map failures error.

We host HDFS on the same cluster with replication factor = 2.

Can someone provide guidance on how to do this?

Having looked at similar posts, I am not not looking to have my job complete on subset of data.

Comment: So, what do you expect as an answer? A ready solution? A link to a tutorial?

Comment: anything I can get :) Even a hint that says "have you looked at this" would be super helpful.